# chrono: can I validate system clock with steady clock on a time scale of an hour?

Tags: c++, time, timestamp, c++-chrono

My application needs absolute timestamp (i.e. including date and hour) with error below 0.5s. The server synchronises via NTP, but I still want to detect if the server clock is not well synchronised for whatever reason.

My idea is to use steady clock to validate the system clock. I assume that within a period of, say, 1 hour steady clock should deviate very little from the real time (well below 0.5s). I compare time measured with steady and system clocks periodically. If the difference between the two grows or jumps large, it may suggest NTP is adjusting the system clock, which may mean that some of the time values were incorrect.

This is an example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main() {
  const int test_time = 3600; //seconds, approximate
  const int delay = 100; //milliseconds
  const int iterations = test_time * 1000 / delay;

  int64_t system_clock = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  int64_t steady_clock = std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  const int64_t offset = system_clock - steady_clock;

  for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    system_clock = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    steady_clock = std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    int64_t deviation = system_clock - offset - steady_clock;

    std::cout<<deviation/1e3<<" µs"<<std::endl;

    /**
     * Here I put code making use of system_clock
     */

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
  }
}
```

Does this procedure make sense? What I'm not sure about in particular is stability of the steady clock. I assume that it might be subject only to a slight deviation due to imperfectness of whatever is the internal server clock, but maybe I'm missing something?

I was very positively surprised by the test results with the code above. Even if I set it to run for 8 hours the maximum deviation I saw was only –22µs, and only around 1µs for vast majority of the times.

Comment: What happens if you try to check when day lights saving comes into effect or during a leap second? `system_clock` is not meant to measure intervals.

Comment: Depending on what your doing, I would either get the time from a server you control as needed, or get it at startup and then track the time elapsed with a `steady_clock`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `system_clock` shouldn't be affected by daylight savings, its UTC

Comment: @AlanBirtles You're probably right, but it's not guaranteed until c++20. It's currently unspecified.

Comment: Why don't you use service of Time.is?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that's a good point, I'm not using c++20 (for reasons I don't control). Is there a way to get it right for me? Do I make a mistake by converting chrono objects to integers with number of milliseconds?

Comment: @ALX23z How time.is would achieve something better than NTP?

Comment: NTP's protocol purpose is clock synchronization between computers - and you want to test absolute accuracy. Time.is a server dedicated to very accurate measurements of time - it has atomic and took care of various other issues. You can compare results between your NTP Server and what Time.is reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has little to do with C++.

1) Whether this method has a chance to work depends on accuracy of your computer's internal clock. Cheap clock might drift a minute a day - which is way over 0.5sec per hour.

2) The method is unable to identify a systematic offset. Say, you are constantly behind by a second due to network lagging, ping, or some other issues. The method will display a negligible deviation in this case.

Basically, it can only tell if time measured is precise but provides little knowledge on the accuracy (google: accuracy vs precision). Also in comments were mentioned issues of the algo regarding general clock adjustment.

Comment: Yes, right, this is more a question about computer hardware. Should I tag it differently?
1) This is exactly what I'm asking about. 1 minute per day sounds scary. The server I'm using probably doesn't fall into "cheap" category, but I still want to know better what can I expect from a PC. Could you provide any links or more detailed information?
2) Yes, thank you for pointing it out. Yes, my only hope was to detect drift or jumps of the clock.

Comment: @user1079505 This is a very niche question. You can try referring to manufacturers manual and check out which clock device they use. Though, they might even lack info on this. If it's important, you can go an extra mile and make your own measurements: purchase an accurate clock device, connect it to PC and compare its results vs `steady_clock` over long period of time to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @user1079505 I found this link: https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~ntp/ntpfaq/NTP-s-sw-clocks.htm it has section regarding what you want.